# Show that $(V_\omega,\in) \models \mathrm{Power\ set}$

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

Let "$\mathrm{Power\ set}$" denote the Power set axiom. I'd like if some of you could tell me if the solution of the following exercise is correct.

I want to prove that $(V_\omega,\in)\models \mathrm{Power\ set}$, namely $(V_\omega,\in)\models \forall x \exists y \forall z (z\subseteq x \rightarrow z \in y)$.

Let $a\in V_\omega$, notice that $P(a)$ itself belongs to $V_\omega$. In fact, since $a\in V_\omega$, then $rk(a)\leq n$, for some $n\in \omega$. If $z\in P(a)$, then $z\subseteq a$, so $rk(z)\leq rk(a)$. It follows that $rk(P(a))\leq n+1$ and so $P(a)\in V_\omega$.

Now, since $P(a)\in V_\omega$ for all $a\in V_\omega$, we have that $\mathrm{Power\ set}$ is satisfied in $(V_\omega,\in)$ because, for all $a \in  V_\omega$, $(V_\omega,\in)\models \forall z (z\subseteq a \rightarrow z\in P(a))$. In fact suppose that $a\in V_\omega$ and that for $z\in V_\omega$ $(V_\omega, \in)\models z\subseteq a$. So we have that $(V, \in)\models z\subseteq a$ $(**)$, because the "formula" "$z\subseteq a$" is absolute over $(V_\omega,\in)$ since it is a $\Delta_0$-formula and $V_\omega$ is transitive. Finally, from $(**)$ we have that for all $z \in V_\omega$ $z\in P(a)$.

And so we have that $(V_\omega,\in)\models \mathrm{Power\ set}$.

Comment: $PA$ means power set axiom? I am so confused because PA is a synonym of Peano Arithmetic in usual.

Comment: You're right, I should have specified it. I mean the power set axiom.

Comment: Looks fine to me; though you may want to tidy and tighten it up a bit.

Comment: @GME: if I want to prove that $(M,\in)$ is a model of the power set axiom and I prove that for any $a \in M$ I have that "the real" $P(a)\in M$, I can't conclude that PA is true in $(M,\in)$, unless I know that $M$ is transitive. Right?

Comment: That's right - it's a good exercise to try and cook up a non-transitive model $M$ which contains $P(x)$ for $x\in M$ but which doesn't satisfy the powerset axiom.